# Tensorflow plot training loss versus number of iterations

Tags: tensorflow, plot, iteration

I am using tensorflow to train a simple linear model and I want to draw a plot where the x-axis is the number of iterations and the y-axis is the training loss. I attach my codes below.

```
d = 1000
N = 10000
X = np.random.rand(N,d) 
theta = np.random.uniform(-2,2,[d,1])
y = X@theta + 2           
y = y.reshape(y.size,) + np.random.randn(y.size)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[d,],use_bias=False)])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss="mse")
callbacks = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(update_freq='batch')
history = model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size = 32, callbacks=[callbacks] )
```

I use callback here, but I can only show this plot using TensorBoard. But, I do not want to use it. Is it possible to compute training loss at each iteration and use plotting modules, e.g. Matplotlib, to draw a plot?

I tried to use callback. I also know how to use history to draw a plot, but using history only allows me to draw training loss versus epochs.